# .net core Service reference - An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, .net-core

I have an issue communicating with WCF service from my `.Net core 2.1` web application, using generated service reference. *Everything works fine from my local environment, but as soon as i deploy the web application to server, the calls are crashing with*:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: An HTTP Content-Type header is
>   required for SOAP messaging and none was found.

Service it self works fine and can be properly called using service reference inside another web app, built on `asp.net 4.7.2`

**What i already tried:**

- I installed runtime and hosting for `.net core 2.1.7` and `2.2`
- I tried adding custom content-type header to the request using this [c# web service client: how to add custom header to request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870077/c-sharp-web-service-client-how-to-add-custom-header-to-request)
- I tried running Wireshark on the server to see the request, seems like no request is leaving the application.
- I tried publishing the web app with different configurations, but even in self contained mode, issue persists
- I tried different message version bindings, only the one in code provided works

Here is the custom binding, client creation and requeste execution code:

```
CustomBinding result = new CustomBinding();

TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
{
    MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressing10  // Soap11 message version causes content-type mismatch
};

result.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);

HttpTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement
{
    AllowCookies = true,
    MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue
};

result.Elements.Add(httpBindingElement);

Client = new ServiceClient(result, new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl));




return await Client.GetServiceStatusAsync();
```

Here is the ConnectedService.json for the service reference:

```
{
  "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15.0.20628.921",
  "ExtendedData": {
    "Uri": "%anonymized%/service?wsdl",
    "Namespace": "Service",
    "SelectedAccessLevelForGeneratedClass": "Public",
    "GenerateMessageContract": false,
    "ReuseTypesinReferencedAssemblies": true,
    "ReuseTypesinAllReferencedAssemblies": true,
    "CollectionTypeReference": {
      "Item1": "System.Array",
      "Item2": "System.Runtime.dll"
    },
    "DictionaryCollectionTypeReference": {
      "Item1": "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2",
      "Item2": "System.Collections.dll"
    },
    "CheckedReferencedAssemblies": [],
    "InstanceId": null,
    "Name": "Service",
    "Metadata": {}
  }
}
```

Here is the relevant part of stack trace for the error:

```
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

**Any ideas where to look next?** I've pretty much exhausted every possible approach i could find, or think of.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the http headers to see differences between working and non working apps.  Depending on the webbrowser installed the default headers from a Net application can be different.  The issue could be with cookies.  Try removing cookies in working machine and try again.  It may not work.

Comment: The main difference is, that the requests to the service are not even leaving the web app on the server (Wireshark just shows TCP pings between servers, acknowledges etc., no actual requests being transmitted, so there is no way to compare them ...). As to the cookies, i changed the AllowCookies property of the client to false and no change. Removing cookies also did absolutely nothing. As to the browser, the request is performed by hosted service on the backend, before any request from any user is even made, so there is no way that it is affected by it.

Comment: http messages uses TCP for transport layer.  The max datagram for TCP ~1500 bytes.So a request/response consists of 1 or more TCP datagrams.When you go secure additional port number are opened.I suspect connection is closing during the TCP and there probably is a [FIN] in the sniffer data.TCP will send multiple times if no ACK occurs.Trace stack confirms what I suspect is the connection to the proxy server is failing.Try manually using a webrowser to go to site.Usually when it fails it will provide instructions on installation of a certificate.The message should appear in the TCP sniffer data.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I deployed the web app directly to the same server as the called WCF service and the calls are passing, so it's definitely network related. I also checked in with our support guys, and this is what was found: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect` . So for some reason it is trying to use https, even though SSL is disabled, and in Startup.cs i commented out both **app.UseHsts()** and **app.UseHttpsRedirection()**